# JOIN MySQL tables based on condition

Tags: mysql, join, union

I have two MySQL tables **users** and **task_reg**

**users**

```
id name
1  user1
2  user2
3  user3
4  user4
5  user5
6  user6
7  user7
8  user8
9  user9
```

**task_reg**

```
top_id  use_id  payment 
1       1       1 
1       2       1
1       4       1
2       3       1
2       5       1
```

I have to display all the users and also show whether they have paid or not

here is my SQL command but it only shows the paid users

```
SELECT users.id, users.name, task_reg.payment
FROM task_reg
JOIN users ON users.id = task_reg.use_id
JOIN topics ON topics.id = task_reg.top_id
WHERE topics.id = 1
```

**Result**

```
id  name    payment
1   user1   1
2   user2   1
4   user4   1
```

**Expected result**

```
id  name    payment
1   user1   1
2   user2   1
3   user3   0
4   user4   1
5   user5   0
6   user6   0
7   user7   0
8   user8   0
9   user9   1
```

[DB-Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/bWrpK2cRURFnRdjrSoawrk/1)

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Since you want all the users, it should be your first table in the join order.
- Change your `Inner join` to `Left Join`.
- `Where` condition on the `topics.id` should be a Join condition.
- Use [`Coalesce()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce) function to get value of payment done as 0 (because of no matching rows found).

Try:

```
SELECT users.id, users.name, COALESCE(task_reg.payment, 0) AS payment 
FROM users 
LEFT JOIN task_reg ON users.id = task_reg.use_id
LEFT JOIN topics ON topics.id = task_reg.top_id AND topics.id = 1
```

Comment: it's working well but got a trouble with this .for `topics.id = 1` and `topics.id = 2` its rerning the same rows, even though there were no topic having id 2.. and for any values for the topics.id the results are not changing . I think you got this. Help me pls .Thanks

Comment: @Sumithran can you create a DB fiddle ?

Comment: @Sumithran fiddle is empty (I cannot see any query in it). please copy paste the query in comments here. I think you are using `topics.id = 1 and topics.id = 2` ? If yes, instead of that, use `topics.id IN (1,2)`

Comment: @Sumithran There is a topic having id = 2: `2, 'DSP Mod 1', 15, '1', '2018-10-20 11:13:32'`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183163/discussion-between-sumithran-and-madhur-bhaiya).